# OAUTH CANCEL REQUEST B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

During account linkup with social media account, If I accept IdP OAUTH consent screen, linking of social media account with logged in local B2C account happens successfully. But when I try to cancel the consent screen, it displays the below mentioned exception and also it prompts for re-login to B2C instead of maintaining the same session.

error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90273%3a+An+invalid+response+was+received+%3a+%27Error%3a+user_cancelled_authorize%2cError+Description%3a+The+user+cancelled+the+authorization

Can you please provide your valuable input to maintain the same session even if user cancels OAUTH Consent Screen during account linkup process.

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't have the ability to consent or doesn't consent, then they are **not logged in**. 
You haven't received the access token or id token yet because the consent is required before you get the access token.

If you would like to have a similar effect of "keeping the user logged in" you would have to make the request again with the same information without the request for the permissions that require consent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Account linkup is provided to the user who are already logged into the web application.  Could you please let me know how to make the request with the same information without requesting OAUTH user consent. As far as I understand, we cant make a request on behalf of user in Azure B2C. Can it be achieved through custom policy where in we can capture user cancellation request from identity provider and send the token based on user logged in object ID. Please suggest.